# Android - File upload works on localhost using Xampp but does not work on server

Tags: android, file-upload

I have made an app that is supposed to let me upload to a server but it only works on localhost. The online server I am using is ueuo.com (free). What might be a solution to this? Funny thing though, the server response code I get is 200.

Here is the app:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "img";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
    private static final String FOLDER_NAME = "/idms/";
    private String imageFileName = "";

    Button btnUpload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        makeDirectory();

        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                        .format(new Date());
                imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX;
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getPath() + FOLDER_NAME + imageFileName);
                Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeDirectory() {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + FOLDER_NAME);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //String pathToOurFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + FOLDER_NAME + imageFileName;
        // Upload the image to the server
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 uploadFile();

            }
          }).start();        

    }

    protected void uploadFile() {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        // DataInputStream inputStream = null;
        String pathToOurFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + FOLDER_NAME + imageFileName;
        String urlServer = "http://idmstest.ueuo.com/upload_api/uploadtoserver.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        Log.d("tester", pathToOurFile);
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));
            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                            + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);
            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.d("tester", pathToOurFile);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            ex.printStackTrace();


            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                             + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
        }
    }
```

Here is the server-side php:

```
<?php


    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```